# How to show number of followers of social network in footer

Tags: facebook

I want to show number of followers of social network (facebook-twitter-googleplus) in footer, but I don't have any idea.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

for facebook like follow this..

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin
```

for twitter follower widget follow this..

```
https://dev.twitter.com/web/follow-button
```

and for google plus...

```
https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/2846874?hl=en
```